# How to use offset parameter of StreamCreateFile in BASS library?

Tags: c#, bass

I am trying to use the [BASS library](http://www.un4seen.com/) to do some audio editing, so if anyone is familiar with the library can hopefully help me.

The function I'm using is

```
Bass.BASS_StreamCreateFile(filename, offset, length, flags);
```

For a little background, I'm using Bass.net wrapper, am working with all mp3 files.  The actual code I'm using this function with is:

```
int baseStream = Bass.BASS_StreamCreateFile(filename, startTimeBytes, durationBaseBytes, BASSFlag.BASS_STREAM_PRESCAN | BASSFlag.BASS_STREAM_DECODE | BASSFlag.BASS_SAMPLE_FLOAT);
```

Whenever the offset  (startTimeBytes) equals 0, the stream is created just fine, but whenever the offset is non-zero, the method returns 0, and the error code given is BASS_ERROR_FILEFORM.  However, the files used work fine without the offset (offset = 0).

Maybe there is something wrong with the flags I'm using or something?

Comment: Sounds to me like it's letting you specify an offset in a composite file to extract your media file from.  Handy for container files that store multiple files in a sequential format.  Probably not intended for what you're trying to do with it.  Or to paraphrase Fezzik: `I don't think it does what you think it does.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mp3 files contain frames without offset. So use `0` offset.
To set the playback position of a stream use **[BASS_ChannelSetPosition](http://www.un4seen.com/doc/#bass/BASS_ChannelSetPosition.html)()**.

1. Create a stream with offset = 0;
2. Translate a time (seconds) position into bytes, based on a channel's format using **[BASS_ChannelSeconds2Bytes()](http://www.un4seen.com/doc/#bass/BASS_ChannelSeconds2Bytes.html)**;
3. Set position with **BASS_ChannelSetPosition()** and `BASS_POS_BYTE` mode.